# Batch file to find multiple string using findstr and copy files to a folder

Tags: shell, batch-file

I am attempting to find multiple strings in files in a directory, there are thousands. I currently run the following command to search the directory:

```
findstr /s "customerid" *
```

Now this allows me to find the file that contains that string. I normally have two pieces of information a customer id and an event type. One customer can have up to 30 associated event such as "website registration".

What I would like to do is, search the directory for both the customer id and the event. Then copy the file to a new location. Is this possible in a batch file?

Comment: Take a look at this [Search XML files in directory for specific string then do copy action using bat script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39577430/search-xml-files-in-directory-for-specific-string-then-do-copy-action-using-bat/39579775#39579775)

Comment: That is a little too confusing, I only know some simply commands :(

Comment: So you are trying to do a sort of AND-operation, so only files that contain both search strings are copied, right? does the position of the search strings (customer, event) within the files matter? It would also be helpful to share a text file excerpt showing the matches. Can they appear anywhere in the text, or are they full words?

Comment: `Findstr "dog cat" etc` finds dog OR cat. As long as your strings don't contain spaces this is simple. Findstr can do more but the syntax is complex (compared to above). You would need to specify exactly what the terms are, as in what characters are allowed, what order they need to be in.

Comment: `Findstr /I "dog" *.txt | Findstr /I "cat"` finds both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Supposing you want to find all files that contain both words (`customer` and `event` in this example), you could use the following script:

```dos
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "PATTERN=*.txt"
set "SOURCE=."
set "TARGET=D:\Data"
set "STRING1=customer"
set "STRING2=event"

pushd "%SOURCE%" && (
    for /F "delims=" %%F in ('findstr /S /M /I /R /C:"\<%STRING1%\>" "%PATTERN%"') do (
        for /F "delims=" %%E in ('findstr /M /I /R /C:"\<%STRING2%\>" "%%F"') do (
            ECHO copy "%%E" "%TARGET%\%%~nxE"
        )
    )
    popd
)

endlocal
exit /B
```

**After having tested the script, remove the upper-case `ECHO` in front of the `copy` command!**

Answer (score 2):

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "sourceFolder=x:\somewhere"
    set "targetFolder=y:\another\place"

    set "customerID=00000000"
    set "event=eeeeeeeeee"

    for /f "delims=" %%a in ('
        findstr /m /s /l /c:"%customerID%" "%sourceFolder%\*" 
        ^| findstr /f:/ /m /l /c:"%event%"
    ') do (
        ECHO copy "%%~fa" "%targetFolder%"
    )
```

`findstr` can deal with it. We only need two instances

1. The first one will search all the input files for the first string, returning only the list of matching files. This list of files will be piped into the second instance
2. The second one will search the second string but only in the files found by the first instance, reading the list of files where to search from standard input stream (`/f:/`)

The rest of the code is just a `for /f` wrapping the two `findstr` commands to process the output of the second one and do the file copy.

**After having tested the script, remove the upper-case `ECHO` in front of the `copy` command!**

Comment: Argh, I totally forgot about the `/F` option... this seems to be the only way to have a single `for /F` loop only... +1!

Comment: @aschipfl, Sometimes I don't see the world that is out of my head and forget to include the OBVIOUS (again in my head) *... remove the `echo` ...*. Thank you.