# How to map numbers to a variable

Tags: batch-file

I have the following script but I want to map the numbers to the variable but do not know how to. So if a user enters 0, I want it to search for the event name NewUser.

```
    @echo off           
    mode con:cols=40 lines=40           
    set /p customerID="Enter Customer ID: "         
    CLS         
    :MENU           
    ECHO.           
    ECHO ...............................................            
    ECHO PLEASE SELECT THE EVENT FROM THE MENU BELOW            
    ECHO ...............................................            
    ECHO.           
    ECHO    Event Code  Event Name  
    ECHO.           
    ECHO    0       NewUser
    ECHO    1       ExistingUser
    ECHO    2       EmailAdded
    ECHO    3       AccountProblem
    ECHO    4       Lost
    ECHO.           
    SET /P event=Type the event code and then press ENTER:          
    IF %event%==0 set event=NewUser GOTO find           
    IF %M%==1 set event=ExistingUser GOTO find          
    IF %M%==2 set event=EmailAdded GOTO find            
    IF %M%==3 set event=AccountProblem GOTO find            
    IF %M%==4 set event=Lost GOTO find          
    pause           
    :find           
    pause           
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion           
    pause           
        set "sourceFolder=C:\test"          
        set "targetFolder=C:\test2"         
    pause           
        set "customerID=%customerID%"           
        set "NewUser=%Event%"           
    pause           
        for /f "delims=" %%a in ('          
            findstr /m /s /l /c:"%customerID%" "%sourceFolder%\*"           
            ^| findstr /f:/ /m /l /c:"%event%"          
        ') do (         
           copy "%%~fa" "%targetFolder%"            
        )           
    pause
```

Comment: Could you please explain what you are looking to copy to %targetfolder%.  1. A file whose name contains the string "%customerID%" with content matching the string "%event%".  2. A file whose content contains both strings "%customerID%" and "%event%"  3. Something different.

Comment: Yes I am looking to copy a file whose contents contains both the strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first version of your code was closer to correct solution than current one; you need to use two nested `for /F` loops as follows:

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('
  findstr /I /m /s /l /c:"%customerID%" "%sourceFolder%\*.txt" 
') do for /f "delims=" %%A in ('
    findstr /I /m /l /c:"%event%" "%%~fa" 
      ') do (
         rem 'copy' command is merely displayed using ECHO for debugging purposes
         ECHO copy "%%~fa" "%targetFolder%"
      )
```

Next *commented* code snippet could help to improve the script:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

set "customerID="
:customerID
set /p customerID="Enter Customer ID: "
if not defined customerID goto :customerID
REM instead of above test, you could apply next statement about `set /P`:
REM    If the user does not enter anything (just presses return) 
REM    then the variable will be unchanged and an ERRORLEVEL will be set. 

rem CLS
:MENU
ECHO.
ECHO ...............................................
ECHO PLEASE SELECT THE EVENT FROM THE MENU BELOW
ECHO ...............................................
ECHO.
ECHO    Event Code  Event Name
ECHO.
ECHO    0           NewUser
ECHO    1           ExistingUser
ECHO    2           EmailAdded
ECHO    3           AccountProblem
ECHO    4           Lost
ECHO.
REM SET /P M=Type the event code and then press ENTER:
choice /C 01234 /M "Type the event code"
REM 0 means that an user's reply to "Terminate batch job (Y/N)?" was not "y" 
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 echo "Ctrl-C" or "Ctrl-Break" pressed&goto :NoSearch
REM 255 means another error
IF ERRORLEVEL 255 goto :MENU
REM  ERRORLEVEL number Specifies a true condition if the last program run
REM                    returned an exit code EQUAL TO OR GREATER THAN the number
REM                    specified.
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 set "event=NewUser"
IF ERRORLEVEL 2 set "event=ExistingUser"
IF ERRORLEVEL 3 set "event=EmailAdded"
IF ERRORLEVEL 4 set "event=AccountProblem"
IF ERRORLEVEL 5 set "event=Lost"
REM Note that in above code, ERRORLEVEL parameters are tested in INCREASING order
REM Used only in this special case
REM           (no need of GOTO statement, 'event' variable is set correctly)
REM 
REM although CHOICE /? says:
REM    When you use ERRORLEVEL parameters in a batch program, 
REM    list them in decreasing order.


:NOTE

set "sourceFolder=D:\test"
set "targetFolder=D:\test2"

rem ??? set "customerID=%customerID%"
rem ??? set "event=%event%"

rem debugging output 
echo looking for "customerID=%customerID%" "event=%event%"

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('
  findstr /I /m /s /l /c:"%customerID%" "%sourceFolder%\*.txt" 
') do for /f "delims=" %%A in ('
    findstr /I /m /l /c:"%event%" "%%~fa" 
      ') do (
         rem 'copy' command is merely displayed using ECHO for debugging purposes
         ECHO copy "%%~fa" "%targetFolder%"
      )
:NoSearch
pause
```

Comment: Hi,That works perfectly however to make it work better, I need it to function with 3 digit event codes? is this possible with the current solution that you have kindly provided?

Answer (score 1):

Change your For loop like this and retest:

```
FOR /F "DELIMS=" %%A IN (
    'FINDSTR/MSC:"%customerID%" "%sourceFolder%\*"^|FINDSTR/MIF:/ /C:"%event%"'
    ) DO COPY "%%A" "%targetFolder%"
```

**EDIT**

I have added a modified version of your script to include the new requirement of a three digit event code. Just adjust it's value in the script as necessary, *(lines nineteen to twenty three)*.

```cmd
@ECHO OFF
MODE CON:COLS=52 LINES=40
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS DISABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

(SET sourceFolder=C:\test)
(SET targetFolder=C:\test2)

SET /P "customerID=Enter Customer ID: "

:MENU
CLS
ECHO=
ECHO= ..................................................
ECHO= PLEASE SELECT THE OPTION FROM THE EVENT MENU BELOW
ECHO= ..................................................
ECHO=
ECHO=      Option      Event Name      Event Code
ECHO=
ECHO.        1.         NewUser           A00
ECHO.        2.       ExistingUser        A01
ECHO.        3.        EmailAdded         A02
ECHO.        4.      AccountProblem       A03
ECHO.        5.           Lost            A04
ECHO=

CHOICE /C 12345 /M "CHOOSE AN OPTION"
SET "Option=%ERRORLEVEL%"
FOR /F "TOKENS=1-4 DELIMS=. " %%A IN ('FINDSTR/BC:"ECHO.  " "%~f0"'
    ) DO IF "%%B"=="%Option%" (SET "Name=%%C" & SET "Code=%%D")

FOR /F "DELIMS=" %%A IN (
    'FINDSTR/MISC:"%customerID%" "%sourceFolder%\*"^|FINDSTR/MIF:/ /C:"%Name%"'
    ) DO COPY "%%A" "%targetFolder%"

PAUSE
```

Please make sure that **%sourceFolder%** is a full path and **%targetFolder%** already exists, *(see line six)*.

Comment: It could not work as to the last `findstr` is piped **name** of a file from the first `findstr` (cf.`/M` parameter). You need two nested loops, see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39948255/3439404).

Comment: Could you please explain that comment @JosefZ. His findstr made sense to me, so I just formatted it to work as a loop. It is supposed to pipe the names of the files containing %customerID%s to another findstr as a file list from the console, that second findstr is outputting those matching file names whose contents contain %event%.

Comment: I have tested the findstr example as a result of @JosefZ's comment. I can confirm that it works perfectly well as I had surmised and posted. If however your filenames or paths contain spaces I'm not sure that the second findstr would read them from the console correctly and your single loop would fail. If that is the case then two loops would be required as per the alternative answer already provided.

Comment: It doesn't work doesn't really help me to help you. I have taken a look at your findstr example, which was provided for you by MC ND [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39845076/6738015), and thought that the only potential issue may be its formatting, however on testing that was also found to be correct. @JosefZ was most certainly wrong, I have also checked it against paths containing spaces and also found it to work perfectly despite my previous doubts. The only potential issue I can see with the code is if %sourceFolder% wasn't a full "drive:\path" _(although your question states otherwise)_.

Comment: Hi, Compo I cannot get it to work with more than 10 options from 0-9? Any pointers?

Comment: Change your option codes from numeric or go back to the uncontrolled `set /p`. This would require a degree of additional coding and to be fair would be outside of the parameters of your original question.

Comment: I have no issues with working with events 0-9 but i have problem 10-35.

Comment: got it :), will retest ... compo do you want to be compensated for your help?

Comment: Yes, _I am shallow and have nothing else to motivate me in life_. As far as your menu system is concerned, I would strongly suggest you look at perhaps a multi menu system where e.g. option 9 goes to next menu. 35 possibilities are kind of unworkable and too much in my opinion.

Comment: The reason that if offered it was I don't want you to think that I am just taking advantage of your kind nature, where you are helping me. What I will do is just donate a little to charity. I like to repay people for helping me.

Comment: The reason that I wanted 35 possibilities is so that it just all on one page. It may seem like quite a few but after a while, I would just get used to the option numbers. Apologies  for offending you earlier.

Comment: If you accept the answer which best suits the requirements of the original question then use that answer in a new question where you provide all 35 option codes and event names, you'd be more likely to get the specific help you require to adapt the code accordingly.

Comment: I just wanted to say your quite awesome and thank you for all your help.